# How to remove X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" from WordPress?

Tags: filters, headers, core, core-modifications

I want to temporarily remove `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` and need to allow all domains.

I have already tried the following ways.

1. Removing `send_frame_options_header` from `./wp-includes/default-filters.php`
2. `remove_action('login_init', 'send_frame_options_header');`
3. Removing `@header( ‘X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN’ );` from `/wp-includes/functions.php`

None of the above doesn't work.

PS: I don't use any security plugin either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this question [How does wordpress restrict X-FRAME to sameorigin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383874/how-does-wordpress-restrict-x-frame-to-sameorigin).

The questioner's issue was resolved by modifying his site's .htaccess file by adding the below line to it as his Web Host set the X-Frame-Option.

```
Header always unset X-Frame-Options
```

You can check if that works for you.